# How to add fictional category wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to do something, on wordpress which i'm not sure is possible. 
So basically, I'm using Magic fields for two things. I've created a panel called "Member", and another one called "Member actuality". I've created two categories, member and member actuality which I've binded too magic fields post.

When I go on category (site.com/category/member) member I have the list of all my members. 
When I click on one of my members (site.com/memberName) I have the description of the member. So for the moment everything is ok.

Now what I want to do is find a way too display actuality of one member. Maybe something like : (site.com/actuality/member) But I have no clue on how to do that. So if someone can help me.

I'm not sure i've explained it right, so please if you didn't understand ask me to reformulate.

Thanks for your future help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do go throu this.

I've first created a new tag when a post was added, and that allowed me to use the tag directory which i didn't used before !

!